# Jsoup select on condition

Tags: jsoup

I have the following html table element:

```
<table class='myTable'>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
    <th>header1</th>
    <td>data1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th>header2</th>
    <td><table><tbody><tr><th>subheader1</th><td>subdata1</td></tr>
                      <tr><th>subheader2</th><td>subdata2</td></tr>
                      </tbody></table></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th>header3</th>
    <td>data3</td>
   </tr>
   ....
 <tbody>
</table>
```

How could I select the headers in the table, where those headers's next td element does not contain a table. In the case above, only select header `header1` and `header3`.

What I have at the moment is

```
Elements elements = doc.select("table[class=" + myTable + "]);
Element table;
if(elements.size()>0){
  table = elements.get(0);
}
else{
  return someMyObj;
}
Iterator<Element> ite = table.select("th AND SOME CONDITIONS").iterator();
while(ite.hasNext()){
     Element header = ite.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    for (Element e : table.select(" > tbody > tr:not(:has(table)) > th")) {
        //DO SOMETHING WITH e
    }
```

The selector selects all th children of tr, that don't contain table and in turn are children of tbody of the context element.

BTW I changed your while loop to for loop, but the idea stays the same.

Comment: Thanks. It works as I expected. Like you said early, I probable try try to squeeze to much from Jsoup.

Comment: Naah, I said it too early cause I thought it can't be done. Then I tried this solution and had to edit the answer ;)